# The shadows in the toon shader are weird

Tags: modeling, shaders, shadows, npr, toon-shading

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJTEJKQ0lYw&ab_channel=MrTriPie.
I watched the video in this link and followed it.
But in my case, there are parts where the shadows are not sharp.

The monkey in the video has sharp shadows.

But if you look at my monkey ears, there are some parts that are not sharp.
[image]

The nodes are connected in the same way.
[image]
I don't know if this is the right thing to do.
Turning off the soft shadows of the shadows in the Render Properties tab makes it a bit better though. but
[image]
This will result in gray instead of black.
First of all, there is no gray in the color lamp, only black and white.
And diffuse bsdf doesn't matter either.
Actually, the character I am modeling is using diffuse bsdf and this problem occurs there too.
[image]
This is my first npr modeling result.
It wasn't perfect, but it didn't matter.
And when I first saw and followed the npr modeling process, I remember that there was no problem like this.
The problem is that I am modeling now, but the shadow seems to have a lot of problems.
[image]
If you look at it now, the shadow is too different from the yellow model.

Please download the file and check if you can see the gray color on the first screen.
I bought a model for reference, but he turned off the soft shadow.
That's why I just tried it.
Is it a matter of light?
Please change the angle and type of light to see if there is a problem like mine in your object.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be best to upload your file, because I honestly can't reproduce your result. For me it looks like in the tutorial, no gray visible. What you show in the last picture I can only achieve if I place a slider with gray color between black and white. But here comes the one problem I got with your question: in your material the sliders are hardly to distinguish because they are so close together. Why? The _Color Ramp_ is set to _Constant_, so the black slider can stay on the left at position 0.0 (like in the tutorial), here I couldn't even tell if there was a gray slider inbetween.

Comment: ...just a quick addition: of course I have turned the _Soft Shadows_ off, they cause what you show in the ear on the second pic (and then it should look like in the video). However he doesn't seem to explain that in the tutorial or I must have missed it.

Comment: Have you got an extra stop in [here](https://imgur.com/a/fEeMqC2) ? Try moving the black all the way to the left, and controlling only with white. Also try:   jump ahead a step in the toot and replace the _Principled BSDF_ with a _Diffuse BSDF_

Comment: I added a file and some sentences to the question. I'd appreciate it if you could check it out.
I don't think there's a problem with what you told me.
I didn't do it here, but I used diffusion bsdf.
And there is no gray on the color lamp. Only black and white exist.
What I think is a problem is not a node or an object, but a blender setting problem, or a wide angle or kind of problem.
Because I already succeeded once and copied many tutorials. I don't think it's a matter of color ramp or diffuse bsdf.

Comment: So I think it's because of the setting, wide angle, and type that I mentioned.
The problem is that I didn't find this error when I first modeled the npr.

Comment: In your light object data properties
In that shadow option, can you tell me if contact shadow is on or if it is set to what value it is? I checked that it changes sharply when this option is turned off, but I want to check if it has anything to do with this.